# TestFlight Not Receiving Notification

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Notify when connecting iPhone to computer and running application but not running when running with testflight.

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZndU.png)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        tokenId = refreshedToken
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload the APNS SSL certificate for Production to firebase. That should solve it. From Developers account App id:

[image]

To Firebase console>Settings icon beside Overview >cloud messaging:

[image]

Comment: [link](https://abload.de/img/screenshot2017-09-19aqpsfp.png) I identified two certificate